# How to List All Redis Databases?

Tags: redis

I ran this command to access my `redis` server.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 6379
```

What is the command to show all of my databases?

Comment: Four decades of IT history in one line (client from 1969, server from 2009).

Answer (score 492, accepted):

There is no command to do it (like you would do it with MySQL for instance). The number of Redis databases is fixed, and set in the configuration file. By default, you have 16 databases. Each database is identified by a number (not a name).

You can use the following command to know the number of databases:

```
CONFIG GET databases
1) "databases"
2) "16"
```

You can use the following command to list the databases for which some keys are defined:

```
INFO keyspace
# Keyspace
db0:keys=10,expires=0
db1:keys=1,expires=0
db3:keys=1,expires=0
```

Please note that you are supposed to use the "redis-cli" client to run these commands, not telnet. If you want to use telnet, then you need to run these commands formatted using the Redis protocol.

For instance:

```
*2
$4
INFO
$8
keyspace

$79
# Keyspace
db0:keys=10,expires=0
db1:keys=1,expires=0
db3:keys=1,expires=0
```

You can find the description of the Redis protocol here:
http://redis.io/topics/protocol

Comment: Thanks for introducing to the Redis protocol along the way..

Comment: `CONFIG GET` doesn't work for me but `INFO keyspace` does

Answer (score 102):

Or you can just run the following command and you will see all databases of the Redis instance without *firing up* `redis-cli`:

```
$ redis-cli INFO | grep ^db
db0:keys=1500,expires=2
db1:keys=200000,expires=1
db2:keys=350003,expires=1
```

Comment: But the same could be achieved with `redis-cli INFO keyspace`

Comment: Downvoting because this is fragile, is likely to break in future releases, and because there is a built in command (as mentioned) to achieve the same result.

Comment: Beware of false negatives when used with wrong search strings, e.g. `$ redis-cli INFO | grep ^db.veri.bad`. Prefer `$ redis-cli INFO keyspace`

Answer (score 52):

you can use `redis-cli INFO keyspace`

```
localhost:8000> INFO keyspace
# Keyspace
db0:keys=7,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db1:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db2:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db11:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most memorable and definitely the most complete way, with `#Keyspaces` section displayed conveniently at the end:

```
$ redis-cli info
```

---

And if you set the password (e.g. with an env var. called `REDIS_PASS`), pass it to the `-a` (auth) arg:

```
$ redis-cli -a $REDIS_PASS info
```