# How to get all the databases stored in redis using python

Tags: python, database, redis

I need to get all the databases stored in redis server using python-redis
Thanks

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, so others can help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look here [List All Redis Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802726/list-all-redis-databases)

Then in python you can do:

```
In [3]: r = redis.StrictRedis()
In [4]: r.config_get('databases')
Out[4]: {'databases': '16'}

In [5]: r.info('keyspace')
Out[5]: {'db0': {'avg_ttl': 0, 'expires': 0, 'keys': 4}}
```

Answer (score 1):

i've tried this

```
import redis
ser = redis.Redis()
print ser.config_get('databases')
```

and the console return this

```
{}
```

and if i put this

```
import redis
ser = redis.StrictRedis()
print ser.config_get('databases')
```

it return this

```
ser = redis.StrictRedis()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StrictRedis'
```

Comment: [official doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis)  redis-py exposes two client classes that implement these commands
 The StrictRedis class attempts to adhere to the official command syntax.
   and  

In addition to the changes above, the Redis class, a subclass of StrictRedis,
overrides several other commands to provide backwards compatibility with older
versions of redis-py  [question answered in  stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021765/redis-py-whats-the-difference-between-strictredis-and-redis)