# Is Redis DB description/title stored somewhere?

Tags: redis

As said in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802726/list-all-redis-databases/12805364#12805364):

> The number of Redis databases is fixed, and set in the configuration
>   file. By default, you have 16 databases. Each database is identified
>   by a number (not a name).

But I am curious if there is a way I could and should *title* and *describe* my databases? Especially in the scenario when one server could be used by few users (developers for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently there isn't such a way. Please also note that numbered (shared) databases are not future-compatible (unsupported by Redis v3 with clustering support) and are not recommended for use - see here for more details: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances