# How can I clear the cache in laravel using command line?

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am using `Redis` to cache queries/routes in Laravel 5.2.

I have 3 environments running on the same web server i.e "production", "staging", and "development."

For each environment I set a different cache `prefix` value to allow me to link the cache to different environment.

In the `config/cache.php` file I changed the line

```
'prefix' => 'laravel',
```

To

```
'prefix' => ENV('CACHE_PREFIX', 'laravel'),
```

Then in my `.env` file, I added the prefix for each environment like this

For Dev

```
CACHE_PREFIX="LaravelDev"
```

For Staging

```
CACHE_PREFIX="LaravelStaging"
```

For Production

```
CACHE_PREFIX="LaravelProduction"
```

I know I can clear the cache from the command line like this

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

But the code above will clear the cache for all of my environments.

I only want to clear the cache for "LaravelDev" only and leave alone "LaravelStaging" and "LaravelProduction"

How can I clear the cache for a specific environment?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CACHE_PREFIX you can use different redis databases. For ex: production => 1, staging => 2, development => 3.
Use this links if you want to be a little bit more familiar with it:

1. [What's the Point of Multiple Redis Databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221563/whats-the-point-of-multiple-redis-databases)
2. [List All Redis Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802726/list-all-redis-databases)

So, in your .env file for each environment (production/stage/dev) you need to define different REDIS_CACHE_DB env value.

Link to the line uses this variable https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/2a2522d8824c0852e30a7e3e07d46a543eb4b33d/config/database.php#L142 .
Examples of .env:

.env.production

```
REDIS_CACHE_DB=1
```

.env.stage

```
REDIS_CACHE_DB=2
```

.env.development

```
REDIS_CACHE_DB=3
```

Don't forget to clear config cache after changing env variables: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What the `cache:clear` artisan command does calls `flush` function on current connector. As caching engines varies with functionality I don't think it's possible to expire keys selectively keeping cache API universal. Engines like Redis provides such functionality, but memcached for example don't.

If you're using Redis you can modify default connector to use 'SCAN / DEL' commands for `flush()` method. Still this is not going to be very effective.

If your application uses cache correctly flushing it should not cause any problems as the cache will rebuild itself. You should never expect some data being in the cache as it might expire anyway.

Comment: When I execute the php artisan cache:clear it erases everything in Redis. I just tested it again. The problem that I am seeing is that the users that are using the app will get Mismatch token error because the session gets cleared too.

Comment: The solution is to use different storage type for sessions in your Staging and Dev environments, so clearing the cache won't affect live users.

Comment: Can't I create a command line that will execute the following code?         $redis = Cache::getRedis();

        $keys = $redis->keys(Cache::getPrefix() . "*");

        foreach($keys as $key)
        {
            Cache::forget($key);
        }

Comment: Sure, that should work as long as you don't have thousands of keys in your cache which could cause it to exceed available memory. Talking directly to Redis you could use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) / MATCH / COUNT command combination.